# ControllerAs not working with es6 syntax

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am receiving the right information in my template with the following setup. But when I am trying to use the controllerAs syntax and refer with

```
{{ app.User }}
```

or

```
{{ $ctrl.app.User }}
```

it's not working. I am using ES6 syntax with a transpiler fyi.

**This setup is working:**

**Template:**

```
<div><h4>Current App Scope User: </h4> {{ $ctrl.User }}</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
class AppController {

  constructor($state, $rootScope, SessionService) {
    this.$state = $state;
    this.User = null;



    $rootScope.$on('UserIsUpdated', (event, user) => {
      this.User = user;
    });

    SessionService.retrieve();
  }

}
AppController.$inject = ['$state', '$rootScope', 'SessionService'];


export const app = {
  controller: AppController,
  controllerAs: app,
  templateUrl: 'app/main/parent/app.html'
}
```

Comment: controllerAs take string in argument, here you are giving app and not 'app', which is kinda weird as it the variable calling itself in the declaration.

Comment: Thanks @Alburkerk

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an AngularJS controller written using ES6 class syntax:

```js
class AppController {

  constructor($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
  };

  $onInit () {
    this.$scope.hello = "Hello, ";
    this.world = "world"
  }

}

AppController.$inject = ['$scope'];

angular.module("app",[])
.controller("AppController", AppController)
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController as $ctrl">
    <h1>ES6 AngularJS</h1>
    <p>{{hello}} {{$ctrl.world}}</p>
  </body>
```

See also, [ToddMoto: AngularJS styleguide (ES2015)](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#angularjs-styleguide-es2015)